# Laravel back() or redirect() does not work in Traits

Tags: php, laravel

I've been using Laravel helpers in all my Traits, assuming that helper functions work everywhere.

But while some functions like `abort()` work, I just realized that `return redirect()` and `return back()` do not work!

Could some one please explain why?

After this, I'm a bit hesitant to trust Laravel... I mean what if next time `abort(403)` doesn't work some where (because I'm not aware of which function works where) and some one does things that they are not allowed to do!

Simplified Example:

```
namespace App\Http\Traits;
trait TestTrait{
    public function doBack(){
        return back();
    }

    public function doRedirect(){
        return redirect()->route('test');
    }

    public function doAbort(){
        abort(403);
    }
}


use App\Http\Traits\TestTrait;
class TestController extends Controller{
    use TestTrait;

    public function testingBack(){
        $this->doBack();
    }

    public function testingRedirect(){
        $this->doRedirect();
    }

    public function testingAbort(){
        $this->doAbort();
    }
}
```

In the sample controller above, `testingAbort()` method works but `testingRedirect()` and `testingBack()` do not! and they shows an empty page instead.

I'm assuming I have to do the redirects in the controller itself (instead of in Traits), but that would cause duplicating a lot of conditional code in controller methods, and I'm also not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a local method and expect the controller to act, you will need to return it, else the controller function will return null and not act on the trait return.

```
public function testingBack(){
    return $this->doBack();
}

public function testingRedirect(){
    return $this->doRedirect();
}

public function testingAbort(){
    return $this->doAbort();
}
```

}